# automower in the frost

Tags: lawn

I have a robotic lawnmower and recently ran it when the grass was white with frost. Now there are some tracks where the grass looks black and almost burned, only where the wheels went. What is causing this? It's probably best not to run it in the frost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this before too, what happens is the frost are like tiny spikes on the grass and when you put weight on it, these spikes get pushed into the grass basically killing it. Secondly cutting the grass during this time is also bad because it doesn't grow anymore or very slowly so it has a hard time healing from the cuts.

Answer (score 2):

You've answered your own question correctly - grass should never be cut if it is covered in frost or frozen, regardless of the type of mower used. The black marks you see may be with you for some time till the grass grows properly again - I'm surprised the tips of the grass are also not dark brown or blackened. It will recover over time, however bad it looks now, but don't cut it again in such conditions.